# How to extract encoded information from VVC compression log VTM?

Tags: compression, hevc

I am trying to extract encoded information like this from the VVC compression-log. Is there any setting, config in EncodeApp source for writing output values to file, I am using VTM Encoder Version 8.2. Thanks
[lick here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIY3t.png)

Comment: There are different solutions depending on what information you need. So what exactly do you want to extract from bitstreams?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to extract the information frame by frame to a CSV file 
such as
line1:  Frame 1, I FRAME, bit-rate, PSNR
line n: ....
.....

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty unrelated to the topic of video compression.
But anyway... What you may do is to read the console output and parse it. To do so, you can first write it into a text file by adding `> log.txt` at the end of your command line. Then, parse the text file and write it to a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the screen context as *.txt ( for instance:`EncoderApp.exe -c xxx.cfg>Enc.txt`, and convert `Enc.txt` to `Enc.csv`( Implemented in Python )